# How to trim collection fields name or column name

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I have three columns (`First Name , Last Name and phone Number`) in my collection that I got from excel using "**copy as collection**" functionality of Excel VBO.

Please note that there is extra space at the end of `First name and Phone number`. I want to trim these spaces. Please suggest how to do that. Please also note that I have not defined the column names in my collection. I am directly copying it from excel so that if any changes done in excel then it reflect in the collection dynamically.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple action in collection manipulation object. You need to use read field action and rename field action with some logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can for use action:

```
Object: Utility - Collection Manipulation
Action: Trim Collection
```

If you don't have it in your object, then you can add it to your object. Please see code below:

```
Dim i as integer
Dim j as integer

'For Each Column As DataColumn In Input_Collection.Columns
For j = 0 to Input_Collection.Columns.Count -1
    For i = 0   to Input_Collection.Rows.Count -1
        'dim x as string =CStr(Input_Collection.Rows(i)(j)).Trim()
        Input_Collection.Rows(i)(j)= CStr(Input_Collection.Rows(i)(j)).Trim()
    Next
Next
Output_Collection = Input_Collection
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you may use

Object: **Utility - Collection Manipulation**

Action: **Remove dot from headers**
and in the code  change  "." to " "

Please find the exact code below and paste it in the code stage:

```
For Each Column As DataColumn In Input_Collection.Columns
   Column.ColumnName=Microsoft.Visualbasic.Replace(Column.ColumnName," ","")
Next
Output_Collection = Input_Collection
```